# Find power series solution for $y''-xy=0$ close to $x=0$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Find power series solution for $y''-xy=0$ close to $x=0$.

$\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}-x\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=0$

Then,
$a_{n+2}(n+2)(n+1)-a_{n-1}=0 \implies a_{n+2}(n^2+3n+2)-a_{n-1}=0 \implies a_{n+3}=a_n\cdot \frac{1}{(n+3)(n+2)}$

I got two problems:

$(1)$ The answer is $a_{n+3}=(n+3)(n+2)a_n$ , where am I wrong ?

$(2)$ How can I find the general power series solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) You're not wrong, $a_{n+3} = \frac{a_n}{(n+3)(n+2)}$.

(2) In order to find the general coefficients try calculating (in terms of $a_0, a_1, a_2$) the first coefficients $a_3, a_4, a_5, a_6, a_7, \ldots$ and look for a pattern. Don't expect a "closed form" for them, for example

$$a_{12} = \frac{1\times 4 \times 7 \times 10}{12!}a_0$$

and you may use the gamma function to write the numerators more succinctly:

$$1\times 4 \times 7 \times 10 = 3^4\frac{\Gamma(13/3)}{\Gamma(1/3)}$$

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the pattern (not very simple, I agree), there is a closed form for the coefficients
$$a_n=\frac{3^{-2 n/3}\,\, \Gamma \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)}{   \Gamma \left(\frac{n+2}{3}\right) \Gamma \left(\frac{n+3}{3}\right)}\left(a_0+a_1 \cos \left(\frac{2 \pi  n}{3}\right)+a_2\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  n}{3}\right) \right)$$

Comment: From the first terms of the expansion of the equation one gets $a_2=0$. /// $a_0$ should only influence the $a_{3k}$, not every coefficient.